UnmanagedCallersOnly symbols not visible in .net AOT compiled executable
Function in AOT executable:
[UnmanagedCallersOnly(EntryPoint = "Add")]
static int Add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

C++ loader code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h> 

typedef int (*add_func)(int, int);

int main()
{
    void* handle;
    add_func add;
   
    handle = LoadLibrary(L"AOTTest.exe");

    if (!handle) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to load library");
        return 1;
    }


    add = (add_func)GetProcAddress((HMODULE)handle, "Add"); 

    if (!add) {
        fprintf(stderr, "No add");
        FreeLibrary((HMODULE)handle);
        return 1;
    }

    int result = add(3, 5);
    printf("Result of Add(3, 5): %d\n", result);

    FreeLibrary((HMODULE)handle);


    return 0;
}

The output of the loader is: No add.
I also ran dumpbin /EXPORTS to see what symbols are exported and the output was:
File Type: EXECUTABLE IMAGE

  Summary

        2000 .data
        2000 .pdata
        A000 .rdata
        1000 .reloc
        1000 .rsrc
       17000 .text
        1000 _RDATA

Is it limitation of the AOT?
